# Laravel - Attribute casting does not cast serialised value to array

Tags: arrays, laravel, serialization

I have a model in which I have the following cast:

```
 protected $casts = [
    'formatted_criteria' => 'array'
 ];
```

It is stored in the database as a serialized array but when I retrieve it why doesn't it automatically revert back to an array?

Instead I'm having to use an accessor to unserialize back to an array.

Comment: Double check you are using a `TEXT` column type

Comment: *The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains **serialized JSON**, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model*  -- [Source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting). From what I understand in your question you are using `serialize` rather than `json_encode` to store the array?

Comment: @apokryfos yes I'm using serialize to store in a text field. I don't wish to store it as json becuase when I cast json back into an array it doesn't preserve the order of the keys. so from the documentation it seems the cast  to array can only be used to unserialze json and not an serialized array?

Comment: Yes exactly. Use a mutator/accessor to use `serialize` I think that's the only way

Answer (score 0):

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

class Serialize implements CastsAttributes
{
public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
{
return serialize($value);
}

```
public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
{
    return unserialize($value);
}
```

}

```
protected $casts = [
    'package_document' => Serialize::class,
    'package_dates' => Serialize::class,
];
```